# Изменение названия таблицы в колонке CLOB. Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle

в оракле есть схема. В ней таблица.

MD_CONTROL

```
CONTROL       VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)               NOT NULL,
  CONTROL_VERS  NUMBER                          NOT NULL,
  FORM          NUMBER,
  FORM_VERS     NUMBER,
  CAPITOL       NUMBER,
  CAPITOL_VERS  NUMBER,
  ID_MD         NUMBER,
  FORMULA       VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE)             NOT NULL,
  SQL_TEXT      CLOB                            NOT NULL,
  PRIORITATEA   VARCHAR2(1 BYTE)                NOT NULL,
  DATA_REG      DATE                            NOT NULL,
  STATUT        VARCHAR2(1 BYTE)
```

В колонке SQL_TEXT       добавляется  SQL.
Например.

```
(
SELECT
  'Rindu 1200 nu este completat' AS REZULTAT

FROM
  CIS.VW_DATA_ALL D


WHERE 
  (D.PERIOADA IN(:PERIOADA)) AND
  (D.CUIIO=:CUIIO               OR :CUIIO = -1) AND
  (:CUIIO_VERS=:CUIIO_VERS     OR :CUIIO_VERS = -1) AND
  (D.FORM = :FORM               OR :FORM = -1) AND
  (D.FORM_VERS=:FORM_VERS       OR :FORM_VERS = -1) AND
  (D.CAPITOL=:CAPITOL           OR :CAPITOL = -1) AND
  (D.CAPITOL_VERS=:CAPITOL_VERS OR :CAPITOL_VERS = -1) AND
  (D.ID_MD=:ID_MD               OR :ID_MD = -1) AND
   D.FORM = 1 AND
   D.CAPITOL = 2
  )
```

Теперь. Я должен изменить название таблицы в которой  есть

```
VW_DATA_ALL
```

Но не трогать в которой есть `(VW_DATA_ALL_TEMP)`  или `(VW_DATA_ALL_COEF)`

Я написал UPDATE.
Условие он должен изменит название только таблицы, не колонки и так далее.

```
UPDATE CIS2.MD_CONTROL  A SET (A.SQL_TEXT) =  (
            SELECT B.SQL_TEXT
             FROM (                                                     
              SELECT 
                  CONTROL,
                  CONTROL_VERS,
                  TRIM(REPLACE(dbms_lob.substr(SQL_TEXT,5000,1),'VW_DATA_ALL','VW_DATA_ALL_TEMP'))  SQL_TEXT
                  FROM (
                   SELECT *
                      FROM CIS2.MD_CONTROL 
                      WHERE
                      1=1
                      AND 
                      (dbms_lob.substr(SQL_TEXT,4000,1) NOT LIKE '%VW_DATA_ALL_TEMP%'
                      AND 
                      dbms_lob.substr(SQL_TEXT,4000,1) NOT LIKE '%VW_DATA_ALL_COEF%')
                      )) B
                      WHERE 
                      A.CONTROL = B.CONTROL AND A.CONTROL_VERS = B.CONTROL_VERS)
                      WHERE EXISTS 
                      (
                      SELECT *
                      FROM (
                      SELECT 
                      CONTROL,
                      CONTROL_VERS,
                      TRIM(REPLACE(dbms_lob.substr(SQL_TEXT,5000,1),'VW_DATA_ALL','VW_DATA_ALL_TEMP'))  SQL_TEX
                      FROM (
                    SELECT *
                     FROM CIS2.MD_CONTROL 
                      WHERE
                      1=1 AND 
                      (dbms_lob.substr(SQL_TEXT,4000,1) NOT LIKE '%VW_DATA_ALL_TEMP%'
                      AND 
                      dbms_lob.substr(SQL_TEXT,4000,1) NOT LIKE '%VW_DATA_ALL_COEF%')))  B
                      WHERE 
                      A.CONTROL = B.CONTROL
                      AND A.CONTROL_VERS = B.CONTROL_VERS   
                      );
```

**Насколько он оптимальный и правильный.**

А если такой запрос ?

```
SELECT
  'Rindu 1200 nu este completat' AS REZULTAT

FROM
  CIS2.VW_DATA_ALL D 

  INNER  JOIN CIS.VW_DATA_ALL DD ON (D.CUIIO = DD.CUIIO AND D.CUIIO_VERS =  D.CUIIO_VERS)  


WHERE 
  (D.PERIOADA IN(:PERIOADA)) AND
  (D.CUIIO=:CUIIO               OR :CUIIO = -1) AND
  (:CUIIO_VERS=:CUIIO_VERS     OR :CUIIO_VERS = -1) AND
  (D.FORM = :FORM               OR :FORM = -1) AND
  (D.FORM_VERS=:FORM_VERS       OR :FORM_VERS = -1) AND
  (D.CAPITOL=:CAPITOL           OR :CAPITOL = -1) AND
  (D.CAPITOL_VERS=:CAPITOL_VERS OR :CAPITOL_VERS = -1) AND
  (D.ID_MD=:ID_MD               OR :ID_MD = -1) AND
   D.FORM = 1 AND
   D.CAPITOL = 2
```

или

```
SELECT
  'Rindu 1200 nu este completat' AS REZULTAT

FROM
  CIS2.VW_DATA_ALL D 

  INNER  JOIN CIS.VW_DATA_ALL DD ON (D.CUIIO = DD.CUIIO AND D.CUIIO_VERS = D.CUIIO_VERS)  


WHERE 
  (D.PERIOADA IN(:PERIOADA)) AND
  (D.CUIIO=:CUIIO               OR :CUIIO = -1) AND
  (:CUIIO_VERS=:CUIIO_VERS     OR :CUIIO_VERS = -1) AND
  (D.FORM = :FORM               OR :FORM = -1) AND
  (D.FORM_VERS=:FORM_VERS       OR :FORM_VERS = -1) AND
  (D.CAPITOL=:CAPITOL           OR :CAPITOL = -1) AND
  (D.CAPITOL_VERS=:CAPITOL_VERS OR :CAPITOL_VERS = -1) AND
  (D.ID_MD=:ID_MD               OR :ID_MD = -1) AND
   D.FORM = 1 AND
   D.CAPITOL = 2

   AND D.PERIOADA NOT IN (  

SELECT 
      D.PERIOADA

      FROM
      CIS2.VW_DATA_ALL D 
      ) ;
```

Comment: А что будет, если в одном запросе в этом поле будет использоваться и таблица VW_DATA_ALL и что то с _TEMP. Или например это будет не имя таблицы, а значение текстовой константы (собственно как в вашем UPDATE)... задачи по замене только имени таблицы гарантированно можно решить только полным синтаксическим анализом текста, для чего у СУБД просто нет инструментов.Либо выходит, что у вас в этом поле на возможные запросы наложены строгие ограничения, о которых вы не упомянули в вопросе. P.S. и как вы понимаете что в запросе где, при таком форматировании, полдня вчитываться и листать экран надо

Comment: А что касается оптимальности ... exists тут абсолютно не нужен, в where который к update было бы достаточно проверки, что текст содержит VW_DATA_ALL и не содержит запретных слов. т.е. буквально `where ... like ... AND ... not like ... AND ... not like ...` и если все условия, что это подходящие записи уже проверены в where update, то выходит что и в SET подзапросы не нужны, а только одна строка `TRIM(REPLACE(dbms_lob.substr(SQL_TEXT,5000,1),'VW_DATA_ALL','VW_DATA_ALL_TEMP'))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если в тексте не может быть посторонних строк VW_DATA_ALL, например внутри текстовых констант. А так же не может быть, что в одном тексте одновременно встречаются как строки, которые надо менять, так и строки, которые менять не надо, то ваш запрос можно переписать как:

```
UPDATE CIS2.MD_CONTROL
   SET SQL_TEXT=trim(replace(SQL_TEXT,'VW_DATA_ALL','VW_DATA_ALL_TEMP'))
 WHERE regexp_like(SQL_TEXT,'VW_DATA_ALL')
   AND NOT regexp_like(SQL_TEXT,'VW_DATA_ALL_(TEMP|COEF)')
```

Так же обратите внимание, что функции `replace()` и `trim()` могут принимать параметр типа CLOB и в этом случае так же возвращают CLOB.

Comment: SELECT  D.*
  FROM
  CIS2.VW_DATA_ALL D, CIS2.VW_DATA_ALL_TEMP DD  Этот не видит

Comment: @VitalieBancu Логично, это то что я написал в первом своем комментарии под вопросом. И то что описано в ответе как "_А так же не может быть, что в одном тексте одновременно встречаются как строки, которые надо менять, так и строки, которые менять не надо_". Средствами СУБД, без глубокого синтаксического анализа текста вы не отловите все подобные ситуации. Так что единственный путь - вытаскивать на клиента все строки которые хоть как то похожи и разбирать их там более серьезными средствами, хотя бы PCRE совместимыми регулярными выражениями.

Comment: @VitalieBancu Хотя ... можно попробовать убрать проверку на "неправильные" названия. И сделать сложный вложенный replace, сначала заменить VW_DATA_ALL_TEMP например на ZZ_DATA_ALL_TEMP, потом заменить то что требуется, после этого заменить ZZ_ обратно

Comment: UPDATE   CIS2.MD_CONTROL
    SET SQL_TEXT=trim(replace(SQL_TEXT,'ZZ_DATA_ALL_TEMP','VW_DATA_ALL_TEMP'));
    UPDATE  CIS2.MD_CONTROL
    SET SQL_TEXT=trim(replace(SQL_TEXT,'VW_DATA_ALL','VW_DATA_ALL_TEMP'));
    UPDATE  CIS2.MD_CONTROL
    SET SQL_TEXT=trim(replace(SQL_TEXT,'VW_DATA_ALL_TEMP','ZZ_DATA_ALL_TEMP'));

Comment: У меня получилось 3 updates.

Comment: UPDATE   CIS2.MD_CONTROL
    SET SQL_TEXT=trim(replace(SQL_TEXT,'ZZ_DATA_ALL_TEMP','VW_DATA_ALL_TEMP'));
    UPDATE  CIS2.MD_CONTROL
    SET SQL_TEXT=trim(replace(SQL_TEXT,'VW_DATA_ALL','VW_DATA_ALL_TEMP'));
    UPDATE  CIS2.MD_CONTROL
    SET SQL_TEXT=trim(replace(SQL_TEXT,'VW_DATA_ALL_TEMP','ZZ_DATA_ALL_TEMP'));

Comment: @VitalieBancu Ну это можно было бы и в одном сделать. просто вложенными `replace(replace(replace('TEMP','ZZ'),'ALL','_TEMP'),'ZZ','TEMP')`  и текущий вариант у вас как то потерял таблицы _COEF ... возможно regex_replace с соответствующей регуляркой несколько упростил бы задачу

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62850/discussion-between-vitalie-bancu-and-mike).

Answer (score 0):

Как уже сказал Mike в комментариях, достаточно просто написать что-нибудь вроде `where ... like ... AND ... not like ... AND ... not like ...`, но есть нюанс. Символ `_` - такой же спецсимвол, как и `%`, и означает он "один любой символ". Поэтому такой запрос вернет 2 строки:

```
select * 
  from (select '1234' a from dual union all 
        select '12_4' a from dual) 
 where a like '12_4'
```

И если у вас случайно попадется какое-нибудь `VW_DATA1ALL`, вам понадобится что-то вроде этого:

```
select * 
  from (select 'траляля VW_DATA_ALL парампампам' a from dual union all 
        select 'траляля VW_DATA_ALL_TEMP парампампам' a from dual union all 
        select 'упс VW0DATA0ALL что это' a from dual union all 
        select 'бывает же VW1DATA1ALL1TEMP такое' a from dual union all 
        select 'траляля VW_DATA_ALL_COEF парампампам' a from dual) 
 where a like '%VW\_DATA\_ALL%' escape '\'
   and a not like '%VW\_DATA\_ALL\_TEMP%' escape '\'
   and a not like '%VW\_DATA\_ALL\_COEF%' escape '\'
```

И стоит убедиться, что в ваших запросах строки, похожие на `VW_DATA_ALL` - это всегда названия таблиц, и нет других объектов БД или строковых констант с такими символами.